# Achieving wait-time accuracies in FreeRTOS environment

Tags: freertos

Part of a software designed on FreeRTOS, I am implementing a specific application layer protocol over the serial port where I have a requirement to wait/poll for certain milliseconds. For example, I send a message over to a device asking for acknowledgement and the system should strictly wait for 200ms until the acknowledgement is received from the receiver else transmit the message again. Is there a way to accurately (say within ± 5% tolerance) achieve wait timings in FreeRTOS, provided I do have other tasks running at the same priority. Not sure if `vTaskDelay()` will provide repeatable results all the time due to factors like CPU load, other tasks executions, etc. Is there a better way to design such an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

VTaskDelay should be okay. It will give you a delay between the requested delay time and the requested delay time - 1 rtos tick.

It may cause issues if your system is heavily loaded and tasks of the same or higher priority run for too long. If there are tasks of the same priority that do not yield in some way then they will round robin on each tick.

The other way to do it would be to use a hardware timer and interrupts, but 200ms +- 5% tolerance should be easily achievable with careful design and priority assignments.

Comment: Yes, but remember that FreeRTOS timers run in a task context and the priority of that task is up to you.